# How to make HTML table cell to flow below other cells in the same row

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which I need to add another cell per column, and since that column will have a lot of elements on it, the cell content must flow below the other cells in the same row, filling all the available width on the table. This way the columns won't be stretched making it impossible to view its content.

A visual example might help: http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw9009157520507047228

**Edit**

After reading all the replies I realize that perhaps I didn't provide enough information. My apologies.

The table I want to modify is the one in http://staging.locamotion.org/projects/pootle/ . Note that this table uses the **sorttable** JavaScript library for sorting the table.

I have to modify that table to display tagging information for each of the entries. Since every entry can have several tags which can span a lot of space, the new column (necessary to keep working the sorting library) must flow below the other columns to allow showing the tagging stuff which can span to one or more lines due to width constraints (have in mind that this program is used on third world countries will old equipment and low resolution screens).

Someone asked what I've tried. I tried adding an additional row per each entry, which only one cell with colspan attribute, but that way the sorting library doesn't work:

```
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>  
            <th>Col 3</th>  
            <th>Col 4</th>                   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>  
            <td>3</td>  
            <td>4</td>                   
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td colspan="4">First entry tagging stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>  
            <td>7</td>  
            <td>8</td>                   
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td colspan="4">Second entry tagging stuff</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- More and more entries -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have any other idea on how this UI can be achieved while keeping column ordering I would appreciate it.

I want to apologize again, and also thank the people who spent some of their time trying to answer and help me the best they could.

Comment: post valid link or post what you have tried?

Comment: I updated my initial question with more data.

Answer (score 2):

Tables cells are ALWAYS rectangles and cannot "flow" as described in your image.

You would need to nest a table in a DIV and use CSS floats to accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible in HTML.

You could create a Div with a left-floated table in it that contains the two cells, and then have the third cell's content as the content of the div (after the table).

```
<div>
  <table><tr><td>First</td><td>Second</td></tr></table>
  Third with a lot of content that might actually span under the table but it's not part of the table
</div>
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/9QS44/

Comment: AFAICT using nested tables won't allow using http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
I updated my initial question providing a more detailed description of what I need, and what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the cells from 2 rows using rowspan and similarly for the columns using colspan. You can also combine both the rowspan and colspan. Not sure if you will be able to achieve the effect you're trying to get, but this is the only way I know that will get you close. This should also help you out. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

Comment: I already tried using colspan. I updated my question since after all it wasn't as clear as I believed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous posters that HTML table cells do not exactly work the way you are wanting. Here's another way to skin the cat:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">

table {
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #FF0000;
}

table td{
border:1px solid #FF0000;
}
    table#child {
        width:200px; float:left;
    }
    table#parent {
        width:300px;
        }

</style>
<table id="parent">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="child">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>                   
                </tr>
            </table>Text that<br />wraps<br /> and wraps.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Might want to reduce the amount of bottom margin on the child table as well so that the text wraps a little bit closer.

If it were me, I'd explore using divs for this particular need and forget about tables altogether.

Comment: AFAICT using nested tables won't allow using http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
I updated my question with a more detailed description.